# ShortUrl: why does it choose one line over another?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^ihome/([^/]+) /index_ip.php?page=ihome [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

When I go to site.local/ihome.... it goes to index.php?page=ihome.
Yet the ihome rule is above it.

I have tried it the other way around too.

I need to force ihome to a particular template file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the first rule requires a `/` to be present, and at least one non-`/`-character after that.  The second rules does not (note the `?` after the `/`. That's why browsing to `ihome` sends you to `index.php?page=ihome`.

You could modify your first rule to something like `^ihome/?([^/]+)?` so the slash and characters are optional. The rule by first looks a bit strange though, as it would skip `ihome/example/secondslash` aswell. Is that intended?